# yum + how to identify the installed rpm with lower version

Tags: regex, bash, rpm, yum, rhel

The goal is to compare the list of rpms under folder `/tmp/list_of_rpms` to installed rpm, and if the package is installed with a lower version then print this rpm.

The approach to check if rpm is installed or not can be easily verified with

```
rpm -qi  gssproxy-0.7.0-30.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
package gssproxy-0.7.0-30.el7_9.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

but actually this rpm installed with lower version as

```
rpm -qa | grep gssproxy
gssproxy-0.7.0-29.el7.x86_64
```

Can we identify also if rpm is installed with lower version?

The approach to take the installed rpm by `rpm -qa | grep gssproxy`
and then comparing it to the rpm file `/tmp/gssproxy-0.7.0-30.el7_9.x86_64.rpm` by regex is very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dedicated tool called `rpmdev-vercmp` for comparing RPM versions.  It's <del>in the `yum-utils` package.</del> *apparently in a package named `rpmdevtools`.*

Untested, but hopefully sufficient to get you started:

```
for rpm in /tmp/list_of_rpms/*.rpm; do
    base=${rpm#/tmp/list_of_rpms/}
    pkg=${base%-*-*}
    if installed=$(rpm -q "$base"); then
        rpmdev-vercmp "$pkg" "$installed" >/dev/null 2>&1
        case $? in 12) echo "$installed is less than $pkg";; esac
    fi
done
```

This doesn't do anything for packages which are not installed at all; perhaps you want to add an `else` clause and add a notification about those, too?

Some background from https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/06/how-to-compare-rpm-version-bash-script-python-linux-algorithm/ but the actual code in that has problems. Also, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163702/bash-script-to-verify-that-an-rpm-is-at-least-at-a-given-version

Comment: `${base%-*-*}` assumes the package version number always contains a dash. I don't know if this is entirely correct.

Comment: yum-utils-1.1.31-54.el7_8.noarch is already installed but the cli  rpmdev-vercmp not exist  ( we have RHEL 7.9 version )

Comment: maybe we need to install the rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch ( from https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2478901 )

Comment: Yeah, probably; I did not try to install it. (That "knowledge base" page is pretty worthless as it requires you to register to see the answer.)